# Can Exchange block emails by presence in a contact folder (or some other kind of folder)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I would like to use an inbound rule for a catch-all domain in exchange online, but also selectively block certain receiving addresses.

Is there an easy way to have Exchange block all incoming emails that match such a condition (eg. recipient address in certain contact folder or a email for the same recipient in a certain email folder)? Basically emulating some dynamic lookup.

I do not want to create custom rules or exceptions for each blocked address, I do not want to send them to the junk mail folder and I want to allow users (not admins) to add addresses to the blocking "folder".

Comment: For Outlook client, there is no built-in option to create such a rule.